# How to know if X variable affects Y variable in (A) model more significantly than (B) model

Tags: statistical-significance, multivariate-analysis, multiple-comparisons

I am investigating the impact of X variable on Y variable (and its three dimensions: Y1, Y2, Y3) using four models:

Y = X1 + control variables
Y1 = X1 + control variables
Y2 = X1 + control variables
Y3 = X1 + control variables

(1) How can I know if X affects Y more significantly than Y1 or Y2 or Y3, considering that the impact of X on all these variables is significant and positive.
(2) How can I compare the impact of X on the three dimensions (Y1, Y2, and Y3).

Note:

- The Ys values are different
- I am using cross-sectional data

Comment: Have you considered multivariate or seemingly unrelated regression?

Comment: Have you considered standardized betas?

Comment: Hi Dimitriy & BigBendRegion. Thank you very much for your help. No, I have not, actually, I am new to statistics. So please may you clarify more about the suggested methods. Thank you very much for your time and efforts. Much appreciated!